# nuxt Highcharts more gives addevent of undefined

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, nuxt.js

I have a simple polar chart and I cannot turn on more=true (nuxt 3, "nuxt-highcharts": "^3.0.9")

```
<highchart :options="chartOptions" more />
```

vue script
[image]

```
  computed:{
    chartOptions(){
    return {
     chart: {
              polar: true
            },
    
            title: {
              text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
            },
    
            subtitle: {
              text: 'Also known as Radar Chart'
            },
    
            pane: {
              startAngle: 0,
              endAngle: 360
            },
    
            xAxis: {
              tickInterval: 45,
              min: 0,
              max: 360,
              labels: {
                format: '{value}°'
              }
            },
    
            yAxis: {
              min: 0
            },
    
            plotOptions: {
              series: {
                pointStart: 0,
                pointInterval: 45
              },
              column: {
                pointPadding: 0,
                groupPadding: 0
              }
            },
    
            series: [{
              type: 'column',
              name: 'Column',
              data: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
              pointPlacement: 'between'
            }, {
              type: 'line',
              name: 'Line',
              data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
            }, {
              type: 'area',
              name: 'Area',
              data: [1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
            }]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @nam vo, I recommend you use the officially supported wrapper for Highcharts in Vue: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-vue It can also be used for Nuxt projects. Related thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue/issues/73